# search for element within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `data[l][m]` contains `1,2,3,4,5`
I'm trying to search for a particular number, say '2' in it. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for (var n = 0; n < data[l][m].length; n++) {
    if(data[l][m][n] == num){ // num is equal to '2'
        number = data[l][0];
        document.form.options[l-1] = new Option(number,number,true,true);
    }
}
```

And how about in: `['id1',['a',[1,2,3,4,5]],['b',[3,4,5,6,7]]]`
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already including jQuery, use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), like this:

```
if($.inArray(num, data[l][m]) > -1) {
  number = data[l][0];
  document.form.options[l-1] = new Option(number,number,true,true);
}
```

The shorter vanilla JS version is a direct [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the Array, but IE doesn't have this by default.

Comment: @DGT: Note that all `inArray` is doing is what you've done; but as you're already using jQuery, might as well save some lines and debugging (and as a by-product it reuses the loop-invariant `data[l][m]` which I'd otherwise recommend you cache to a local).

Comment: Thanks guys, but can I also use inArray to search within nested array such as ['id1',['a',[1,2,3,4,5]],['b',[3,4,5,6,7]]]?

Comment: @DGT - Yup, it's still just an array when you're iterating over it, regardless of where it's located.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), although it still has the same O(n) complexity as your for loop:

```
var pos = data[l][m].indexOf(num);
if (pos !== -1)
{
  // element was found
  number = data[l][0];
  document.form.options[l-1] = new Option(number,number,true,true);
}
```

Note, however, that older versions of IE do not have the `indexOf` method for Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have no major changes to recommend, but do have a couple tweaks to suggest. The first is to create a temporary reference to `data[l]` to reduce reading complexity by 1 level. This is a cosmetic change for the benefit of the coder. The other is cache the length of the array you are searching, which helps with performance. If you replace your `for` loop with the `while` loop as follows, you can also remove the comparison operations.

```
var layer1 = data[l];
var n = layer1[m].length;
while (n--) {
    if (layer1[m][n] == num) { // num is equal to '2' 
        number = layer1[0];
        document.form.options[l - 1] = new Option(number, number, true, true);
    }
}
```